# My system for earning cash every two minutes isn't working. Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I want to make it so that every two minutes you earn $3 I want this to be the case whether your playing the game or not the ammount of money you earn this way caps at 21600 (after 24hours passes.) and you will be able to claim the money after you press a button "ClaimCash".

My approach was to save the last time you played in your user data and subtract it from the current time and then devide it by 120. This way you can see how many '2 minutes' have passed. I called the function `calculate_cash_earned()`

Ok. Let me get to the problem. The first time I started the game every thing worked fine and the money to claim was going up by $3 every 2 minutes. I closed the game and waited a while to see if it worked while I wasn't playing and I came back and that seemed to be working also. So I claimed my cash and the button reset to $0 and closed the game and reopened it in the span of a few seconds so not enough time for more cash to accumulate and to my suprise the Button didn't show $0 to claim but instead the same ammount as before I closed the game. This was weird because I did claim it and it showed in the ammount of cash I had.

Here is my code, I suspect it has something to do with the _process(_delta) function:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@onready var ClaimCash = $ClaimCash

var config = ConfigFile.new()
var lastplayed
var cashearned = 0

func _ready():
    if config.load("user://user_data.cfg") != OK:
        config.set_value("user", "user_lastplayed", Time.get_unix_time_from_system())
        config.save("user://user_data.cfg")
        lastplayed = config.get_value("user", "user_lastplayed")
    else:
        if not config.has_section_key("user", "user_lastplayed"):
            config.set_value("user", "user_lastplayed", Time.get_unix_time_from_system())
            config.save("user://user_data.cfg")
            lastplayed = config.get_value("user", "user_lastplayed")
        lastplayed = config.get_value("user", "user_lastplayed")
        cashearned = calculate_cash_earned()
        ClaimCash.text = str(cashearned)
        config.set_value("user", "user_lastplayed", Time.get_unix_time_from_system())
        config.save("user://user_data.cfg")

func calculate_cash_earned():
    var current_time = Time.get_unix_time_from_system()
    var elapsed_time = current_time - lastplayed
    var increments = int(elapsed_time / 120)
    cashearned = increments * 3
    return min(cashearned, 21600)

func _process(_delta):
    var current_time = Time.get_unix_time_from_system()
    if current_time - lastplayed >= 120:
        cashearned = calculate_cash_earned()
        ClaimCash.text = str(cashearned)
        lastplayed = current_time

func _on_claim_cash_pressed():
    var current_cash = config.get_value("user", "user_cash")
    var new_cash = current_cash + cashearned
    config.set_value("user", "user_cash", new_cash)
    config.save("user://user_data.cfg")
    cashearned = 0
    ClaimCash.text = str(cashearned)
```

I tried instead of resetting `lastplayed` every two minutes in the _process(_delta) function, I made a new variable with the same value as last played. It looked like this:

```
func _process(_delta):
    var current_time = Time.get_unix_time_from_system()'
        var lastearned = lastplayed
    if current_time - lastearned >= 120:
        cashearned = calculate_cash_earned()
        ClaimCash.text = str(cashearned)
        lastearned = current_time
```

This didn't work + it added another problem. When I clicked on the button to claim the cash didnt reset to 0 instead it just stayed the same I didn't even have to reopen the game this time.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, when the player pressed the button, the amount to add depends on the time elapsed since the prior time the player pressed the button.

Thus, a natural implementation would store the time when the button was pressed. This is pseudo code:

- Read the time the button was last pressed.
- Get the current time.
- Compute the elapsed time.
- Store the current time.
- Compute how much to increment based on the computed elapsed time (you can implement the cap here).
- Read the stored amount.
- Compute the new amount by adding the computed increment.
- Store the new amount.

Since you are already storing the new amount every time, storing the time also won't be an issue. Of course, you need to have starting values for the stored amount and the last time the button was pressed, which would be zero and the current time when the game is launched for the first time (i.e. when there is nothing stored).